# Custom login module for admin users in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am trying to develop a customer login module for Drupal. I have gotten the flow to work but when an admin user tries to login, I get a Integrity Constraint Violation error.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'admin' for
```

My Code structure is:

```
function module_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  return module_form_user_login_alter($form, $form_state);
}

function module_ldap_form_user_login_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  unset($form['links']);
   $form['#validate'] = array('user_login_name_validate',
    'module_ldap_login_validate',
    'user_login_final_validate',
   );
}

function miniorange_ldap_login_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  // Code to authenticate users. if authenticated
  user_external_login_register($username, 'module');
  $form_state['uid'] = $user->uid;
}
```

For other users, it does not try to create the user, instead just logs in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are missing some serious codes,what is the name of your module? 'module' ? or 'miniorange'? why some of your function are start with 'module'? where is `$username` comming from in `miniorange_ldap_login_validate` function ?

Comment: here is  a step to step simple toturial for what you are trying to do : https://api.drupal.org/comment/13434#comment-13434